# Combine Row value of mysql table to array value

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a table with 6 column. I want the row selected values to access as array values.
below is my query

```
$currentActiveBingoCard = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT id FROM wp_kkfl_bingo_numbers where activate_status =1");
```

I have below mysql table which I want all 5 numbers in array.

[image]

Please suggest.

Comment: What do you have so far, where is your code?

Comment: Please edit your question and paste all relevant information there, noone wants to scroll through the comments to get what you're after. Also hard to read in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to join all number fields as one string with values separated by comma you can do it with MySQL [CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function:

```
SELECT CONCAT(number1, ',', number2, ',', number3, ',', number4, ',', number5) as joinedValues FROM `wp_kkfl_bingo_numbers` where activate_status=1
```

Comment: this is the perfect solution. thanks. ill update with this line of code.

Answer (score 1):

I got answer to my question after spending sometime.Hope this will help others.

```
$getBingoScoreboards = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT number1,number2,number3,number4,number5 FROM `wp_kkfl_bingo_numbers` where activate_status=1",ARRAY_N );

$joinedValues =  implode(",",$getBingoScoreboards[0]);
```